# @media configuring for high res / ipad / iphone

Tags: html, css, mobile

I've literally wasted the entire day trying to figure this out.

When I resize my browser to anything of lesser width than 778px, the screen goes black. (any height works, just width doesn't configure)

What i would like to do is add a mobile @media setting that actually displays what I currently have!

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}
```

any ideas what's wrong with my code? I've been rain-man'ing through my css..

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/jwrg5/

Much appreciated!

Comment: Can you be specific on what is the problem? I mean what do you get know and what would you expect to get instead? I can see you gave a link to an external CSS file on Fiddle, but it has close to 1000 lines of CSS -- I bet you nobody here is gonna go through all that.

Comment: Hey, you're right... Honestly I like to see anything except a black screen when making the window narrower than 778px.. Just wondering if someone could check my one @media and possible add another one to make anything appear? This whole max-min ###px is confusing me :S

Comment: If you add some html markup that shows the actual problem, I'm sure someone will pitch in and troubleshoot

Answer (score 1):

Here is a clinical example for applying media queries ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4yQAg/)):

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    body {
        background: red;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 481px) {
    body {
        background: blue;
    }
}
```

The stylesheet functions as follows:

- When your viewport is wider than 480 pixels, blue background is rendered
- Narrower viewports are rendered red.

Note that there is a difference between using `max-width` and `max-device-width`. The latter gives you the maximum device width, which does not allow you to as easily test your queries by resizing your browser window.

Comment: Your simplistic example was really helpful.. I had way too many @media tags and I was getting confused.. thanks!